# Bypassing event watcher in java program with batch file

Tags: java, batch-file, jar

I'm currently trying to automate some data export from a monitoring program written in JAVA. I don't have the source code so I got a JAVA decompiler to look inside my .jar file.

I found the functions that I want to execute but I don't manage to execute them by commands in cmd prompt.
When I launch the .jar file, the main() function starts, it launches two event watcher threads that wait for actions. The actions that I want to perform are normally accessed trough buttons pressing.

I tried launching hese functions directly but my batch lines aren't even read. The only read line is the first one, launching the program, then nothing, it just waits and doesn't read the other lines.

I'm a bit lost and I could sure use some help !

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please review [MCVE] and show us the batch code you've tried so far, tell us why you think it's failing and exactly what you expect it to do.

Comment: Hi,
I continued my investigation and found out that you can't launch a function from within a java class from batch, you can only launch a class itself, then you'll need a main() method in the class you want to launch.

So what I want is impossible this way. Thanks for your help anyway ;)